# How to set a 0 default value within a range of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using a range of cells (columns F-G-H) for estimation purposes, and having an estimate of 0 hours is acceptable, however blank/empty is not. Seeing as users can add rows as they see fit I want to ensure that all cells in columns (F-G-H) except for the header (row1) default to 0 (and the user can change / overwrite it) if needed.

Is there a way I can enforce this for newly created rows for this specific range? I know I can use a formula in the existing cells but that doesn't help for rows that are user-created after the fact.

(BTW - simularily for column C I want to default the cell to "WI-" and for column D I want to default the cell to "REQ-", etc...).

Any help/hints/ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain why *"an estimate of 0 hours is acceptable, however blank/empty is not"*?

Comment: Blank could infer that it was not considered whereas 0 is clearly a 0-hour task. And management has mandated that all cells be filled with a valid value.

Comment: Surely if management require a valid value, the default *should* be blank (implying "not entered yet"), not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

1. Enter the number 1 in an unused cell
2. Copy that cell.
3. Highlight the cells in which you want blanks replaced by zeros.
4. Choose Edit > Paste Special from the menu.
5. In the Operation section of the  dialog box select Multiply and click on OK.
6. Numeric cells won't change and Cells containing any text data will be ignored.
7. All blank cells will now contain a zero.

For this to apply to newly added rows, use the `Worksheet_Change` event in which you will predefine your range where this will be applicable. Simply record a macro for the above steps and use that code in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Also remember to use proper error handling and set `Application.EnableEvents = False` and reset it again in the error handler.

> (BTW - simularily for column C I want to default the cell to "WI-" and for column D I want to default the cell to "REQ-", etc...).

For this the above method will not work. You will have to handle that in VBA